# How to make buttons not merge in table tds - BS4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

The bootstrap button themes are quite useful so I tried including them in interactive table data. No matter the type of td (button or not), when adding the button classes on click events, the tds on the same row clicked will merge.

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm  table-hover">
<thead>
            <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">1</th>
                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                    <th scope="col">4</th>
                    <th scope="col">5</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td  id="x4y3" name="x4y3" value="-1">_</td>
        <td  id="x2y3" name="x2y3" value="-1">_</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
            //alert(currentModal);
            //alert($(this).val());
            var val = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            if(val > 1 || val < -1 || val === NaN) {
                $(this).attr('value', 1);
                $(this).removeClass();
                $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
            }
            else {
                switch(val) {
                    case -1:
                        $(this).attr('value', 0);
                        $(this).removeClass();
                        $(this).addClass('btn btn-secondary');
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        $(this).attr('value', 1);
                        $(this).removeClass();
                        $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $(this).attr('value', -1);
                        $(this).removeClass();
                        $(this).addClass('btn btn-danger');
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7yvqfg/) demonstrates the problem if you click on the cells.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that the btn class has "display:inline-block" which is messing up the td's display as a table-cell.

I'd suggest adding a button into to the cell rather than making the cell itself a button.

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
            //alert(currentModal);
            //alert($(this).val());
            var val = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            if(val > 1 || val < -1 || val === NaN) {
                $(this).attr('value', 1);
                var btn = $("<button>");
                btn.addClass('btn btn-success');
                $(this).append(btn);
            }
            else {
                switch(val) {
                    case -1:
                        $(this).attr('value', 0);
                        var btn = $("<button>");
                        btn.addClass('btn btn-secondary');
                        $(this).append(btn);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        $(this).attr('value', 1);
                       var btn = $("<button>");
                    btn.addClass('btn btn-success');
                    $(this).append(btn);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        $(this).attr('value', -1);
                        var btn = $("<button>");
                btn.addClass('btn btn-danger');
                $(this).append(btn);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

This will append the button to the table each time you click it.You'll have to add code to prevent that.